# near-sdk-rs - unit testing promises

Tags: unit-testing, nearprotocol, near-sdk-rs

What is the right (intended) way to test promises and their results in near-sdk-rs? Please, point me in the right direction (docs/examples/...).

Let's take the simplest example (from here https://www.near-sdk.io/promises/token-tx): `Promise::new(account_id).transfer(amount)`.

How to unit test that the right account received the right amount?

Answer (score 0):

Check the example of fungible-token at near-sdk-rs repositories. You will get your answer.

Here is the right way for checking the balance given in the example.

[checking_balance](https://github.com/near/near-sdk-rs/blob/a903f8c44a7be363d960838d92afdb22d1ce8b87/examples/fungible-token/ft/src/lib.rs#L137)